# Why does my Regular Expression ignore the last character in each match

Tags: javascript, regex

Below regex works properly except that it ignores the last character in each match.

```
\d{4}\b.*?(?=[^:]\d{4}(?! ml| kg)( [A-Za-z]{2}| \d{1}-| 1H-| [A-Za-z0-9],[A-Za-z0-9]| \D{1}-)|$)
```

My question is:
How can this be updated to also include the last character in each match

Below an example of the data:
https://regex101.com/r/XRlr4Q/1

Comment: Can you show examples of what it's supposed to match and what it's matching instead?

Comment: Hi MK01111000, please add an example for the failing case, adding input, output and your expectation what should have happened.

Comment: FYI `{1}` is never needed. Every pattern matches 1 time unless you have some other quantifier.

Comment: I suspect the lookahead is matching the last character. So the regexp matches everything before that.

Comment: Hello Barmar and IngoSteinke, I added an example

Comment: @Barmar. Thank you for your comment on the {1}. I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[^:]` pattern in the lookahead requires a char other than `:` before the first four digits of a match.

You need to use a lookbehind `(?<!:)` there:

```r
\d{4}\b.*?(?=(?<!:)\d{4}(?! ml| kg)(?: [A-Za-z]{2}| \d-| 1H-| [A-Za-z0-9],[A-Za-z0-9]| \D-)|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XRlr4Q/3).

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote a bit your Regex to match

- 4 digits
- Followed by your special char and unlimited [A-a]
- Then a positive lookahead to match everything until it sees the start sequence again or the end of file

I removed some things which you can add again if needed, but it works with your dataset.

> \d{4}( [A-a]+).+?(?=\d{4}( [A-a]+) | $)

Here an example based on your DataSet :
https://regex101.com/r/HWYJEf/1